# Object expansion in functions calls

Tags: java

If I have a string like:

```
String myColor = "Color.RED";
```

How do I get that to work in:

```
graphics.setColor(myColor);
```

I guess I'm asking how do I pass a variable object name to a function.  I've tried a bunch of stuff and can not get it working.

Comment: Now I don't feel so bad.  I was really hoping have this work in a simple way.  I use varible expansion in other languages and its hard to get my mind around doing it, or something like it in java.  So this is not just around the Color object.  I currently just put the graphics.setColor(Color.RED) but I wanted to create a method call that was more generic.  So maybe I should ask a different question.  Instead of how to do that, what is the best way to do this kind of thing from the start?

Comment: @dude: Basically, your internal representation of a color should be an instance of the java.awt.Color class, since that's what it's for. You may have to convert the Color to or from some other representation, in order to get it in or out of your application, but don't do it until you actually have to. I can't tell you any more, since I don't know what your application does, but hopefully this will give you the general idea.

Comment: The final way I did this was based off Erick's post:  

String myColor="RED";
try {g.setColor((Color)Color.class.getField(myColor).get(null));}
 catch (NoSuchFieldException e) { } 
 catch (IllegalAccessException e) { }

I didn't include the exception handling blocks for space's sake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need error checking to make sure the string is valid, but the crux of it is this:

```
graphics.setColor((Color) Color.class.getField("RED").get(null));
```

Of course, you'll also have to use string manipulation to take the "Color." part out of the string.

Comment: I got this working with:
String myColor="red";
graphics.setColor((Color) Color.class.getField(myColor));

Answer (score 2):

There are some fancy, dirty tricks with the reflection API, but the easiest solution would be a map from Strings to the values:

```
Map<String, Color> colorMap = new HashMap<String, Color>();
colorMap.put("Color.RED", Color.RED);
```

and later on, when you need a color:

```
String myColor = "Color.RED";
graphics.setColor(colorMap.get(myColor));
```

Comment: Pssh, `Color.RED` doesn't return `int`. It returns `Color`.

Comment: while this is clean I really wanted something more dynamic.  But I have a few other areas this would be cool with.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want write this in plain java, you must produce tons of code (using split by '.' ClassForName, getFields and so, so on...). Or you may use many bean helpers, i.e. [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/), or get some examples from projects, already working with reflection (i.e. [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/))

Answer (score -1):

Can't really dereference a constant like that.

Use `Color.getColor("Color.RED".split("\.")[1])` to get the same thing.

If you were to try and use the string you'd have to do something like:

```
String[] parts = myColor.split("\.");
String className = parts[0];
String fieldName = parts[1];
Class c = Class.forName(className);
Field f = c.getField(fieldName);
Object o = f.get(null);
Color col = (Color) o;
```

In conclusion - don't.

Comment: This doesn't work for `"Color.RED"`. According to the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getColor%28java.lang.String%29) it takes a system property key.

Comment: Agreed.  This solution does not work.  It will get the system property as an integer, then interpret that integer as a color.

Comment: It will work for "RED" - "Color" is not part of the colour name, it is the class. Updated answer to reflect that.

Comment: But it's essentially true--If you have something you would normally have in code (Color.RED or a variable name or an object name) in a string, you have to use reflection to actually do anything with it--and honestly you should avoid reflection unless there just isn't any other way.  Using a string like "red" and passing that to color is a much better idea.

Comment: and this not work with properties like "Colors.SolidColors.RED"

Comment: Yes, this is nonsense - I have spent too much time doing C# - you can do basically the above like this.

Answer (score -1):

Scecifically for enumerations (like the Color thing, but not only), see the [Enum.valueOf][1] method.

[1]: http://cupi2.uniandes.edu.co/~cupi2/sitio/images/recursos/javadoc/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class, java.lang.String)